# Why use QVector(Qt) instead of std::vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I'm very new to C++ and Qt, but I'm very good at C#/Java.

The point is I like cross-platform, but I'm confuse with Qt. Isn't `std::vector` already cross-platform, doesn't Qt provide an equivalent to a non-crossplatform thing?

Also how are `File` and `QFile` different?

A link would be nice, thanks :)

Comment: There is also no `File` which compares at all to `QFile`. `FILE*` is something entirely different.

Comment: Qt is old, and provides components that, once upon a time, were not available on all compilers. There is not much use for those in new code.

Comment: To add to @Bo Persson's answer: the Qt containers aren't even 64-bit clean. They use `int` for sizes, so they can never store more than 2^31 elements on x86-64.

Comment: I *only* use the Qt containers if I have a to call a function that accepts only a Qt container.

Comment: larsmans but what about this? from Qt documentations: typedef qint64

Typedef for long long int (__int64 on Windows). This type is guaranteed to be 64-bit on all platforms supported by Qt.
Literals of this type can be created using the Q_INT64_C() macro:

 qint64 value = Q_INT64_C(932838457459459);

Comment: @shbk: doesn't matter as long as the class' methods/ivars are defined using int you won't gain any 64bit benefits by simply passing a true 64bit value to it as they get lost in the first implicit cast it passes.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This article loooks good. It compares Qt Template Library with Standard Template Library:

- [QTL vs STL](https://web.archive.org/web/20160902015144/http://blog.codeimproved.net/posts/qtl-stl.html)

Hope, you'll find it interesting seeing all the differences listed there in the article.

EDIT:

Here is what I find interesting:

> My opinion is that the **biggest
>   advantage of the QTL is that it has
>   the same implementation (including
>   binary compatibility) on all OSes
>   supported by Qt**.  Some STL
>   implementations might be below par
>   when it comes to performance or they
>   might be missing functionality. Some
>   platforms don’t even have an STL! On
>   the other hand, the STL is more
>   customizable and is available in its
>   entirety in header files… **Like I said,
>   there is no clear winner**.

Like he said, no clear winner. But still reading the article makes lots of things clear. Its better to know the difference than going for one, without knowing the other.

Comment: By the same viewpoint Qt may be sub-par and missing functionality. And what is *binary compatibility* of a template container?

Comment: Binary compatibility is important for linking to libraries built with different toolchains. This bit us last year... the vendor ended up switching to C-style arrays from std::vector. (Yes, I know this is an old thread...)

Comment: Might someone update this thread? I mean it's been a while since this answer was posted. What about C++11 and C++14, have they brought anything new to the STL's? Isn't C++ now striving to be crossplatform? Just my own curiosity.

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole: C++ was crossplatform from its very beginning.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the STL.

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole: Even STL was crossplatform from its very beginning.

Comment: OK so why does Qt still use its own implementations of STL provided structures?

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole: Short answer : consistency. For long answer, *google* it.

Comment: IMO, as time goes on, due to massive improvements in the STL, it makes less and less sense to use Qt's container classes unless needed for compatibility.

Comment: @Nawaz seems that "QTL vs STL" link is no longer working.

Answer (score 16):

The QVector class is reference counted and is geared to being shared without copying. Qt provides a lot of containers that correspond to STL containers.  A document that describes these with some explanation of the internals and a bit of rationale:

- [Inside the Qt 4 Containers](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq19-containers.html)

Answer (score 10):

From [over here](http://live.gnome.org/gtkmm/FAQ):

> Qt originates from a time when C++ and
>   the standard library were not
>   standardized or well supported by
>   compilers. It therefore duplicates a
>   lot of stuff that is now in the
>   standard library, such as containers
>   and type information. Most
>   significantly, they modified the C++
>   language to provide signals, so that
>   Qt classes can not be used easily with
>   non-Qt classes.

Comment: This is not the whole story and gives a wrong impression. There are still reasons to use Qt containers, not the least being shared memory and the like. But if you're not using anything else Qt, don't use them.

Comment: I don't know if a gtkmm FAQ is the best source for Qt information... At least the part saying that Qt modified C++ language is not true.

Comment: @Roku : How else would you describe the MOC?

Comment: C++ language  leaved untouched

Comment: The moc is a preprocessor for C++, so as to support their meta objects. It compiles Q_OBJECT and other meta object macros, to C++. They thus extended C++; just as C++ is an extension of "C".  You don't usually need to know them, and just code straight C++.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with Qt, but I fail to see how the use of preprocessor macros can "modify the C++" language". Besides, currently, C++ theorists agree that the C preprocessor shouldn't be used in C++, but many established C++ libraries (MFC, WxWidgets, Boost and Qt) make heavy use of the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

Since no answer mentioned it, Qt containers, including `QVector` generally have a fuller API, which does enable a certain amount of extra convenience and reduces verbosity when compared to `std::vector`.

`QVector` isn't really integrated into the Qt APIs, that role is taken by misfit `QList`, so it is not really a strong argument to use `QVector` for overall better compatibility with Qt APIs. Note that this might change for Qt 6, as the shortcomings of `QList` become more and more acknowledged.

That being said, if you already depend on Qt for your application, it would make good sense to use `QVector` for the convenience. I presume that nobody is going to add such a bloated dependency as Qt just for a container or two. `QVector` is efficient and a solid performer, and will run without problems on any platform, supported by Qt.

On the other hand, if you want to make a core logic API that is framework agnostic, it would be a good idea to develop it in standard C++ if possible, so you get something portable that isn't tied to a particular GUI framework so you can easily migrate it to a different one in the future if you need to.

Qt 6 update: Now `QList` and `QVector` are [pretty much functionally identical](https://www.qt.io/blog/qlist-changes-in-qt-6).

Answer (score 2):

I compare Vector and Qvector by this code the vector mush faster than Qvector.
both code implemented in Qtcreator and compiled with visual studio 2019 compiler

```
void qvectortest()
{
    QVector<double> s[10][100];
        for (int is = 0; is < 100000; is++)
        {


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++)
                {
                    s[i][j].push_back(k);
                }
            }
        };
        QVector<double> d;
        d=s[0][0].mid(0);
        d.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {

                s[i][j].clear();

            };
        };
        cout << "Qvector="<<is << endl;
        }
}
```

and

```
void vectortest()
{
    vector<double> s[10][100];
        for (int is = 0; is < 100000; is++)
        {


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++)
                {
                    s[i][j].push_back(k);
                }
            }
        };
        vector<double> d;
        d.assign(s[0][0].begin(), s[0][0].end());
        d.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {

                s[i][j].clear();

            };
        };
        cout << "vector="<<is << endl;
        }
}
```

[copmare operation/Time figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUeid.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The bad experience I've had with `QTL` was related to `QTL` not raising any exceptions; this makes it harder to trace and fix critical errors. Also, `STL` implementations are closely related to a compiler, because parts of the library require compiler-specific extensions to the language. This means a `STL` implementation can often outperform `QTL`, which needs to be portable and therefore cannot benefit from said extensions. The debugging issue was critical for me though.

Answer (score 0):

C++'s `std::vector` is cross-platform because it is part of the C++ Standard.  Every C++-conformant compiler must provide it.

I'm not familiar with Qt, but I did see this [in the docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qvector.html):

> Note: All functions in this class are
>   reentrant.

It's also likely (speculation) that the QVector class is more easily integrated to hold Qt-centric objects than `std::vector` might be.  Again, I'm not familiar with Qt so you have to decide for yourself.

As a rule of thumb (to which there are many exceptions), I would tend to use `std::vector` unless I had a compelling reason to use some library-specific container class.

Comment: reentrant doesn't have any relations to what you mean. Reentrant means that any thread can call a member function on an instance of reentrant class  while no other class call a member function of the same class

Comment: @AlexShulzhenko: Agree about reentrant vs thread-safe.  All reentrant means here is that the internal data store (array) is private and may only be accessed and manipulated via class methods.  Ref: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html#reentrant

Comment: As a general rule this holds true, but Qt is not a library, it is a framework and if you first are using a framework, it makes sense to go all in.