# Wondering about QVector size

Tags: c++, qvector

Just a random question i came across.

If I call `myQVector[121]` but that `QVector` has no item in it, does it create 121 space in that `QVector` or it only create the space named 121 in it?

I want to know because i'm creating a library for my cd(needed a project to learn) and i want to make the vector possible for multi-cd album.

What i mean

```
QVector myQVector;

myQVector[121] = "song number 1 on cd 1";
myQVector[122] = "song number 2 on cd 1";
myQVector[211] = "song number 1 on cd 2";
myQVector[322] = "song number 22 on cd 3";
```

Comment: Is the documentation down or something? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvector.html

Comment: You really think I have'nt looked before? I did'nt found the anwser, that's why I'm asking... thanks anyway. Somebody else got the answer?

Comment: The answer is in the documentation I just linked above.

Comment: Where??? I'm looking at it right now...

Comment: I am a beginner so some word don't make sense. I found something about the default value, but that's not what i'm looking for. Should I look in the regular C++ library? Is Qvector really different from c++ vector?

Comment: It depends on the use-case. There's an SO question dealing with that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623218/why-use-qvectorqt-instead-of-stdvector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`QVector` documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvector.html):

```
QVector myQVector;
```

The [default constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvector.html#QVector) constructs an **empty** `QVector`.

```
myQVector[121] = ....
```

[`operator[](int(i)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d) has condition

> `i` must be a valid index position in the vector (i.e., `0 <= i < size()`).

So calling `myQVector[121]` does not satisfy the conditions.

You may want to have a look at [`QMap`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmap.html), [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I guess I'm going to do a QVector with another QVector in it. I really appreciate the help though. Sorry for bothering you with n0obish question. BTW I would have voted your anwser up, but someone down-voted my question...

Comment: @Chax Glad it helped. Have a look at the map types I added at the end of my answer. They *might* be more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not automatically increase the size (number of items) of the QVector. Instead, your application will crash, because you try to access an invalid index.

But a list/vector does not seem to be right data structure here. I believe, what you really want is a QMap, where you can assign a value to a key:

```
myMap[songId] = "song number 1 on cd 1";
```