# What class of Qt can replace the class CPtrList of MFC?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

The question is as the title: What class of Qt can replace the class CPtrList of MFC?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector` or `std::list`?

Comment: @CodyGray [Why use QVector(Qt) instead of std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5623218/4284627)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest Qt versions (I mean Qt5) there isn't any direct replacement.

But you can some what achieve the similar functionality using `QList<T>`

ex:

`QList<QObject*>` can take all the objects of classes derived from `QObject`.

`QList<QWidget*>` can take all the objects of classes derived from `QWidget`.

You can iterate the list an get the respective objects by type casting.

In Qt3 there was `QPtrList` with very similar name like `CPtrList` in MFC and some what similar functionality, which is obsolete now.

The below link also says somewhat like `QList` is an alternative (look for QPtrList in below link)

https://www.kdab.com/porting-from-qt-4-to-qt-5/

Comment: [Please don't abuse `code formatting`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538). "Qt" is the name of a library, not code.