# accessing and making vectors of class pointers to create multiple objects

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, object, qvector

G'day,

I'm trying to implement a builder design pattern in c++, I essentially followed the guide by Derek Banas from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XnsOpjclUg), which was in Java and tried to move it over. It actually came out alright, everything works apart from this.

So, What I have right now is,

```
ToyBuilder* toy = new NormalToyBuilder( __multiple parameters__ );
```

And Ideally what I want is something like,

```
QVector<ToyBuilder*> toys;

For(int i=0; i<4 ; i++){
        toys[i] = new NormalToyBuilder( __different parameters[i]__);
}
```

My main problem and also the reason I'm posting this question here is I'm not even sure what to search for on stack overflow. An array of pointers?, Vector of Objects? all I can say is all potential search attempts were futile.

I'm not exactly stuck on using Vectors, it's just the most obvious thing I could think off for this kinda situation. I've been stuck on this for ages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you describe what actually is not working? Does your code not compile? Does it segfault? Also, you should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<ToyBuilder> toys;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    toys.push_back(NormalToyBuilder(...));
}
```

You probably don't to use `new`, just put the objects directly in the vector, rather than pointers. But if you do, it should be:

```
std::vector<ToyBuilder*> toys;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    toys.push_back(new NormalToyBuilder(...));
}
```

Depending on how you use these pointers, you might want to use a smart pointer class like `std::shared_ptr` rather than raw pointers.

Comment: "no matching member function for call to push_back". 
On Both of your edits.
Solid try, can't say I haven't tried that already though.

Comment: Is `NormalToyBuilder` a derived class of `ToyBuilder`?

Comment: So why _Use `std::vector()`_ ... whats wrong with `QVector`?

Comment: @MohammadKanan Because `std::vector` is a standard C++ component. I'm not sure what you gain by using QT's replacement, I suspect they're just a legacy from before `std::vector` was standardized.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks. The only _recommendation_ I know about is { _If you are not using Qt, then no reason to use QVector/ or: use std::vector_}, I am not aware of any, but one could find some flaws using QVector, on the other hand it has strong advantages over c++ STL (shared without copying), this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623218/why-use-qvectorqt-instead-of-stdvector?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) along with comments explore better what i can sum up. worth saying, the problem in OP question does not relate to which vector is used.