# How to change a value of an object which is contained in an QVector-array on heap in a simple way?

Tags: c++, qt

Modifying objects which are contained in an QVector array **on stack** can be done like this

```cpp
//widget.cpp
//extract from widget constructor:
QVector<MyClass> myClassObjectsStack;
myClassObjectsStack.push_back(MyClass());
int index = 0;
myClassObjectsStack[index].firstName = "Michael";
```

When QVector array is **on heap** I do now modify objects by three steps:

```cpp
//widget.cpp
//extract from widget constructor:
myClassObjectsHeap = new QVector<MyClass>;
myClassObjectsHeap->push_back(MyClass());

// (1) Assigning myClassObjectBuffer the object which is on heap:
myClassObjectBuffer = myClassObjectsHeap->at(index); 

// (2) Modifying value of buffer object
myClassObjectBuffer.firstName = "Ella";

// (3) Inserting buffer object at index position, like overwrite old object:
myClassObjectsHeap->insert(index, myClassObjectBuffer);
```

Can I do this in a more easy way or is that way appropriate???

Like changing a class object which is on heap is very simple:

```cpp
myClassPtr = new MyClass;
myClassPtr->firstName = "Nelvyn";
```

For information:

```cpp
// myclass.h
class MyClass {

public:
  QString firstName;
  MyClass() { firstName = ""; }
  MyClass(QString nameValue) { firstName = nameValue; }
};
```

```cpp
//widget.h
class Widget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~Widget();
  QVector<MyClass> *myClassObjectsHeap;
  MyClass *myClassPtr;
  MyClass myClassObjectBuffer;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```cpp
(*myClassObjectsHeap)[index].firstName = "Ella";
```

You should consider using `std::vector` instead since it's superior in every way. You can see [this](https://youtu.be/uZ68dX1-sVc?t=116) talk as a nice discussion on that.

Comment: Disagree with your comment that std::vector is superior in every way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623218/why-use-qvectorqt-instead-of-stdvector.

Comment: @mzimmers the thread you're linking is very old. Qt containers are missing a lot of functionality. I couldn't find it, but I am sure I watched a recent keynote by the Qt guys where they basically said Qt-containers are legacy, just use STL.

Comment: Oh...interesting. Thanks for the clarification. Were they referring to all the Qt containers, or just the QVector? I wish I'd seen that keynote.

Comment: @mzimmers I found it https://youtu.be/uZ68dX1-sVc?t=116 . Apparently it's not officially by Qt company, so take it for what it's worth.